# How to restore after accidentally apt-get remove python

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, samba, apt

Yeah. I've done this. It was stupid.

I did not know it's going to take its dependencies with itself, only wanted to install python 2 and 3 from scratch (because of this problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/897355/how-to-change-default-idle-for-python).

Now, I can still use my terminal, checked these answers:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/741265/apt-get-remove-python-150mb-apt-get-install-python-687kb

https://askubuntu.com/questions/437644/i-accidentaly-did-sudo-apt-get-remove-python

However after running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` I get these errors:

```
Setting up python-ldb (2:1.1.24-1ubuntu3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-ldb.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-ldb.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-ldb (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up python-tdb (1.3.8-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tdb.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tdb.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-tdb (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-samba:
 python-samba depends on python-crypto; however:
  Package python-crypto is not configured yet.
 python-samba depends on python-ldb (>= 1.1.2~); however:
  Package python-ldb is not configured yet.
 python-samba depends on python-tdb; however:
  Package python-tdb is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:
 mercurial-common
 python-crypto
 python-dnspython
 python-ldb
 python-tdb
 python-samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Every apt-get install command throws this.

Is there a way to restore these dependencies?

Comment: Try using "apt-get install -f"  It might fix the broken dependencies

Comment: @Abhimanyusingh No, sadly it throws the same :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hallelujah.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python python-chardet python-colorama python-distlib python-django python-django-tables2 python-six python-html5lib python-lxml python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-urllib3 python-requests python-pip python-virtualenv

sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dnspython

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install
```

After a whole day of adventures in the deepest pits of internet, these commands worked for me.

python-dnspython and samba was still missing after the first command, `--reinstall python-dnspython` pulled samba in as well. Autoremove removed the needless dependencies.

Naturally some of these could be quite redundant but I was just following some long lost forum posts all over the place and what matters is that it worked.

Comment: After a few hours of digging, this post saved my sanity and my PC.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 12):

I did the following and was able to recover my system fully:

1) `sudo apt-get update`

2) Ran the 4 commands given above by MattSom (thanks to him):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python python-chardet python-colorama python-distlib python-django python-django-tables2 python-six python-html5lib python-lxml python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-urllib3 python-requests python-pip python-virtualenv

sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dnspython

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install
```

But GUI was still not available. I run below to recover that as well:

3) `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 8):

you can restore everything again by just running

`sudo apt install gnome`

even if you left with kernal only

Comment: Thank you so much, the answer above didn't work and I got scared, but this solved it.

Answer (score 4):

For me this

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3 python3-chardet python3-colorama python3-distlib python3-django python3-django-tables2 python3-six python3-html5lib python3-lxml python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources python3-setuptools python3-urllib3 python3-requests python3-pip python3-virtualenv

sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-dnspython // this was needed 

sudo apt autoremove // there was nothing to autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install // there was nothing dependences.
```

wasn't enough.
I had to run first this line, because my internet connection was broken

```
sudo dhclient -r;sudo dhclient
```

Then run previous block and then this

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-desktop
```

And after all this I had to reinstall my NVIDIA drivers.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this of Ubuntu 20.04+ versions:**

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3 python3-chardet python3-colorama python3-distlib python3-django python3-django-tables2 python3-six python3-html5lib python3-lxml python3-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python3-urllib3 python3-requests python3-pip python3-virtualenv

sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-dnspython

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

reboot
```

**If your ubuntu is stuck on login screen with no response from Keyboard or Mouse, then try this:**

> Reboot -> Advanced Options for Ubuntu -> recovery mode -> network
> -> Yes -> again recovery options will come now select root -> terminal will get started

Run the above commands and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/187227/i-run-sudo-apt-get-remove-python2-7-can-i-restore-my-ubuntu-now

> To do this, manually download the python2.7 package (and its dependencies), and manually install them using dpkg (bypassing APT, which requires Python). Once that's installed, apt should work again, and so apt-get install ubuntu-desktop will restore your system. (If apt-get still doesn't work, you might also need to download and install any missing dependencies.)

Dose that work?

(dpkg) - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dpkg.html

Comment: Yep, this is what I'm trying, find this one as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/565438/deleted-the-python-binary-and-cant-recover-using-apt-get-what-can-i-do 

Gonna report the results today.

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked was to find and fix the Broken Packages on my PC

`sudo apt --fix-missing update`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install -f`