# I removed my database while running 'sudo apt autoremove python'

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, server

I was trying to remove python from my server and I just completely removed mysql. Is that even possible?
It happened while trying:

`sudo apt autoremove python`

Answer (score 2):

### What happened?

Whoops! It seems that many important packages and parts of Ubuntu need python to function (including `apt` itself). This is one of those bad situations that you should try to avoid.

By calling `autoremove`, the python package was uninstalled along with all it's now-unneeded dependencies. However, the packages that need python to work are now left hanging.
*(More on [what autoremove does](https://askubuntu.com/a/527421).)*

It's kind of like if you cut the roots off of a tree- the tree would still be there, but without it's roots, it won't be a very effective tree.

You can [check the apt-get log](https://askubuntu.com/a/741272) to see what was affected.

### How can I fix it?

First, copy any important files you have to an external backup location (or give yourself a high five if you have been keeping regular, up-to-date backups before this happened).

After your files are safe, it would seem that you have two choices.

#### 1. Easy way

Reinstalling Ubuntu is the easiest way out. You'll get restored to a working configuration with python and all other important things intact.

#### 2. Hard way

Here are some other answers detailing how to reinstall the deleted packages for if you want to try and fix this by hand without starting over from scratch. The main problem with doing so is that without python, `apt` won't work, so you need to use something else to reinstall `python` before reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`.

- [Use `dpkg` because `apt` won't work without python](https://askubuntu.com/a/199435)

  > manually download the `python2.7` package (and its dependencies), and manually install them using `dpkg` (bypassing `apt`, which requires Python). Once that's installed, `apt` should work again, and so `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` will restore your system.
- [Using `dpkg` to reinstall python](https://askubuntu.com/a/282574)
- [Ubuntu 13.04 reinstall important stuff using apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/a/384041) (also includes a section on what to do if your GUI is broken as well).

  > Open a text-only virtual console by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.
  >   **At the login:** prompt type your username and press Enter.
  >   **At the Password:** prompt type your user password and press Enter.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55779945/11639533
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/565438/deleted-the-python-binary-and-cant-recover-using-apt-get-what-can-i-do

Comment: I did this: 
after entering command line (I could not enter Ubuntu from GUI) I used `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` you mentioned in your Hard way solution. 

Thank you very much. 

My problem was this:
I removed Python with `sudo apt autoremove python3.9` and removed many packages (500 MB). After I installed Python 3.9 again but missing all libraries that where previously installed... So GUI session was broken...